# Regular Expression to validate a string containing '=' and '~' as end character

Tags: java, regex, spring-boot

In Java, I have to validate a string which contains "~" and '=' at the end using RegEx.

For example:

```
LOCKER=2004-02-23-23.28.22.377655~UCC=0103207031~URY=31/12/9999~URF=23/02/2004~URT=SEREST ISSY LES MO      ~URFC=XX~URFNUMCB=XXXXXXXXXXX~CEB=XXXXX~CEBC=XXXXX~URFN=0001
```

this String format is **KEY1=VALUE~KEY2=VALUE~KEYN=VALUE** uppercase

'~' is as separator

Currently, i am using some regular expresion but all of them false
can anyone help me please ? thank you for advanced

Comment: Does the `~` really belong to the value itself, or is it just some kind of separator?

Comment: @QBrute its belong the value

Comment: i mean '~' belong the string as separator bewteen fields KEY=VALUE~KEY2=VALUE~KEYN=VALUE

Comment: If it's a separator, why do you need a regex? You can just do something like `myString.split("~")` and you get all your key-value pairs as an array, which you can then validate separately.

Comment: @QBrute because i want check if the string contains `=` and `~` as separator

Comment: *"Currently, i am using some regular expresion"* Show us what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex should do:

```
^(?!~)(?:(?:^|~)[^=~]+=[^=~]*)+$
```

*Explanation*

```
^            Match beginning-of-input, i.e. matching must start at beginning
(?!~)        Input cannot start with `~`
(?:          Repeat 1 or more times:
  (?:^|~)      Match beginning of input or match '~', i.e. match nothing on
               first repetition, and match `~` on each subsequent repetition
  [^=~]+       Match KEY
  =            Match '='
  [^=~]*       Match VALUE (may be blank)
)+
$           Match end-of-input, i.e. matching must cover all input
```

Change the characters classes for KEY and VALUE as needed if they have further restrictions, e.g. use `[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*` instead of `[^=~]+` if the KEY has to be an uppercase-only identifier.

If using Java's `matches()` with the regex, the first `^` and the ending `$` is redundant. The second `^` is still required.

Comment: The character before the dollar sign in your regEx: shouldn't it be a plus instead of a star? I don't think it's Ok to match an empty string at all.

Comment: @Chaarmann It could be ok, but you're likely right. Answer updated.